# How to achive switch redundancy between ASA Cluster Control Link

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, failover, etherchannel

I have two ASA 5525-X in cluster. Between them, for Cluster Control Link, I have Switch. When this switch fails, both CCL fail and both ASAs shut down cluster mode. (data interfaces are shut down). ASA in cluster doesnt support connecting to switch stack. What are my options, to achive switch redundancy?

Comment: What do you mean the ASA in a cluster doesn't supports connecting to a switch stack? A switch stack looks like a single switch to any other device, and the other devices have no way to know it isn't a single device.

Comment: I read in cisco documentation that etherchannel in asa cluster don't support connecting to stack of switches. If I create portchannel on one asa and connect one port to one switch and second port to second switch (those ports are in portchannel) and if one switch goes down, CCL will not fail?

Comment: It's no different than having a port channel to a single switch and losing one of the links. The stack is, for all practical purposes, a single switch. The ASA has no idea that it is connecting to a single switch or a stack of switches. I would be curious to see the documentation to which you refer. A link would be nice.

Comment: I will try this in my test environment tommorow, and I will send you tommorow morning link. Thanks for answering

Comment: Which switches are you stacking (3750X, 3850, etc.)?

Comment: I will try with 3850

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa91/configuration/general/asa_91_general_config/ha_cluster.pdf

Comment: Page 8-29: The ASA does not support connecting an EtherChannel to a switch stack. If the ASA EtherChannel
is connected cross stack, and if the master switch is powered down, then the EtherChannel connected
to the remaining switch will not come up.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I still have my doubts and think it's worth testing. I could maybe see a problem with the diagram on page 8-30, but the diagram on page 8-31 I think should work. A stack can't be any different than a chassis with boards. Couldn't you channel across separate boards in a chassis? Would the channel fail if one of the boards died, or the supervisor failed over to the backup? I guess this is why we do lab testing.

Comment: Hi Ron, I just want to tell you that I tested my problem, and it works!! I really dont understand Cisco manual, because it is not correct. I powered off and active-priority 15 switch , and active-priority 1 switch, and everythink worked just fine.

Comment: I really couldn't imagine why it wouldn't. I haven't really found where a stack acts like anything more than a single switch, and the ASA cluster needs to take into account a switch port or board failure. I could imagine some scenario where some sort of failure disabled a channel on one ASA but not another. I guess that could cause a problem.

Comment: I posted an answer, and you should accept it if it satisfies you, otherwise the question will keep coming back and looking for an answer, forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section in the documentation to which you refer says:

> The ASA does not support connecting an EtherChannel to a switch stack.
>   If the ASA EtherChannel is connected cross stack, and if the master
>   switch is powered down, then the EtherChannel connected to the
>   remaining switch will not come up.

There are a couple of diagrams which follow. The next diagram shows an EtherChannel among the ASA, and I think this text may apply to it:

[image]

The next diagram shows each ASA having a separate channel on the switch. This should work on a switch stack. With a stack of two switches, and one switch failing, the EtherChannel of each ASA will fail, but the connections to the switch which stays up should maintain connections between the ASAs:

[image]

I think you are really just looking to maintain the connections between the ASA in the event of a switch failure, and I'm pretty sure that the second diagram will work with a stack, but you should test it to be sure. I just don't see how an ASA could tell it is connected to a stack of switches as opposed to a switch chassis with separate boards.